# Add indicator dynamically to tabhost icon android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-xml, android-tabs

I am using Tabhost in Android app for navigation.  All works well, however one of my tabs is for Messages and if the user has at least 1 message, I'd like to add a textview to the tab icon showing the number of messages the user has.  So basically I have the icon and the text Messages below, and would like to have an additional textview on the top right of the tab icon showing the message count.

I've found posts related to adding text to the tab, however it merely modifies the existing tab indicator textview.  Is it possible to have an additional textview on the tab that I can reference and have set to visibility gone normally, and if messages exist update the visibility to visible and show the count?

I'm guessing I'll need to create a custom XML layout for this tab and use it when calling

`.setIndicator("Messages",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_messages))`

Any insight or examples are greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: what is the problem with appending the number of messages to the "Messages" label?

Comment: @MartinGolpashin because that's not was is required for this app.  I need to have a red circle with the message count show on the tab when messages are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check this example it's work. It's display badge in your tabbar**

[TAB_BAR SHOWING NUMBER](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Answer (score 2):

To archieve this, you would need to implement a custom `TabHost`that overrides the one from the Android framework.

```
public class CustomTabHost extends TabHost {

    public CustomTabHost(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabHost(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Androids TabHost has an inner class called `TabSpec` that implements the following method:

```
public TabSpec setIndicator(CharSequence label, Drawable icon) {
    mIndicatorStrategy = new LabelAndIconIndicatorStrategy(label, icon);
    return this;
}
```

so in order **to add another TextView** to the Tab, you need to **overload this method like this**:

```
public TabSpec setIndicator(CharSequence label, Drawable icon, CharSequence text) {
        mIndicatorStrategy = new LabelIconTextIndicatorStrategy(label, icon, text);
        return this;
    }
```

To make this work, you also need to implement a `LabelIconTextIndicatorStrategy` that works similar to the `LabelAndIconIndicatorStrategy`, but has a text included.

```
private class LabelIconTextIndicatorStrategy implements IndicatorStrategy {

    private final CharSequence mLabel;
    private final Drawable mIcon;
    private final CharSequence mText;

    private LabelIconTextIndicatorStrategy(CharSequence label, Drawable icon, CharSequence text) {
        mLabel = label;
        mIcon = icon;
        mText = text;
    }

    public View createIndicatorView() {
        final Context context = getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View tabIndicator = inflater.inflate(mTabLayoutId,
                mTabWidget, // tab widget is the parent
                false); // no inflate params

        final TextView tv = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final ImageView iconView = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // when icon is gone by default, we're in exclusive mode
        final boolean exclusive = iconView.getVisibility() == View.GONE;
        final boolean bindIcon = !exclusive || TextUtils.isEmpty(mLabel);

        tv.setText(mLabel);

        if (bindIcon && mIcon != null) {
            iconView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
            iconView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if (context.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
            // Donut apps get old color scheme
            tabIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_v4);
            tv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_indicator_text_v4));
        }

        return tabIndicator;
    }
}
```